# How to excute sql query in CS-Cart

Tags: sql, cs-cart

I try to create sql query in `CS-Cart`. But it's not working to me.

```
$category_id = 1;

$company = db_get_array(SELECT `company_id`,`lang_code`,`email`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`zipcode`,`logos`,`company`,`timestamp`,`status`,`opening_hours` FROM `cscart_companies` WHERE `categories` LIKE '$category_id,%' OR `categories` LIKE '%,$category_id,%' OR `categories` LIKE '%,$category_id' OR `categories`='$category_id');
```

The above is code that I query from database but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all try the correct formating of the query like this (you have a mess with quotes):

$company = db_get_array("SELECT `company_id`,`lang_code`,`email`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`country`,`zipcode`,`logos`,`company`,`timestamp`,`status`,`opening_hours` FROM `cscart_companies` WHERE `categories` LIKE '".$category_id.",%' OR `categories` LIKE '%,".$category_id.",%' OR `categories` LIKE '%,".$category_id."' OR `categories`='".$category_id."'");

If this does not work, please post an error here.

But I would recommend to use placeholders for the DB queries: see the documentation: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/core/db/placeholders.html